# gunicorn + django - What are good production level settings to achieve maximum throughput?

Tags: python, django, playframework, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn + django for my application. Since my application does not have any static content to serve, i am not using nginx for now. (I am using a Macbook Pro - 8GB Ram, 2.7GHz, Intel i5)

The only setting that i did was for gunicorn -

```
import multiprocessing
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
limit_request_line = 0
backlog = 2048
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
loglevel = 'critical'
```

I did some load testing using "jmeter" by hitting a very simple controller in my django app, which just echoes back the query parameters (effectively no computation).

I am observing roughly 560 request/second. Is this the best we can get with this tech stack? I even tried "eventlet" and "gevent" with no success.

I did a similar experimentation with Play Framework and was able to achieve 750 request/second with default configuration.

However, when i tried with

```
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 8 + 1
```

i was able to get much better performance, but this configuration feels wrong.

Is python this much slower or i am making some mistake?

**UPDATE:**

I tried using gunicorn behind nginx and was able to achieve some improvement. The request/second improved from 560 to 632. Thanks Daniel for the suggestion. But still this is not close to the performance i am targeting. Am i missing some configurations in django/gunicorn?

Comment: You're never going to get proper performance without using a proper reverse proxy server in front. Just because you don't have any static content (what, really? Not even a basic CSS file?) is no reason not to use nginx.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response. The app is just an API, so it does not have css/html. Most of the documents point towards using nginx as reverse proxy only for static files. Can you help me understand the role of nginx in a setup which does not have any static files.

Comment: I'd rather you pointed me to some docs that say what you claim. A reverse proxy has *no* role in serving static files; when it's doing that, nginx is acting directly as a web server. Rather, a reverse proxy is about buffering requests to the application server (in this case gunicorn): see [the docs](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/stable/deploy.html).

Comment: Thanks Daniel ! You got me there :) I will setup nginx and get back with the results. Do you have any suggestions about the gunicorn/django settings which can help me improve throughput.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried out the nginx approach and got the following results:     632 request/second with "workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1" and 785 requests/second with "workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 8 + 1". This is better than 560 req/sec but i guess we should be able to push this further. Whats your thought? I used unix socket file to connect gunicorn and nginx.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that Play Framework is able to serve 100 concurrent and in total 3000 request with average time of 6 millisecond/request time which is impressive. Can we expect similar response time and throughput with gunicorn?

Comment: Actually even your play numbers looks below what is expected. Could you please share your code?

Comment: Hi Marco, for Play, i am using it behind nginx and with default configurations. With default settings i was able to get pretty acceptable throughput so did not tune it much. However, with gunicorn/django, the story looks different.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the results after using nginx as reverse proxy. The results have improved but i feel there is room for improvement. Any suggestions?